# Infopath Generate Unique ID

Tags: 2010, infopath, infopath-rules

I have question about Infopath Forms.

My condition is,
I have an infopath form with multiple views. I have a workflow on form, that when the form is submitted, it passes through different views. Now when I save on each submit it creates different file(when I use function now()). So how to create unique name which lasts till the workflow ends even form is re-submitted multiple times in views.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @hilary. It really helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field to the main data source for the name - you don't have to display it on the form. Set the submit connection to use this field for the name on submit. In your form load rules, set a rule that sets the new field to the function of now() and add a condition to only set it if the field is blank.

That way if the form is new, and the field is blank, the value will be set to now(), but the value won't be changed over the life of the form.